# how to set focus on new window or tab in Firefox and IE Browsers?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, window, setfocus

I need to set focus on newly opened window or tab in IE and Firefox Browsers
note: the new window must be single instance.

Please someone help to fix issue.